# how to solve Name error in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

When I run Python script in python3 it works well but in python 2.7 I get an error and I should run this code in Python 2.7 :

this is my code:I want to test some algorithms on path-finding and want to create a window consisting of grids where I can drag my mouse while clicked to create walls and delete them with right click and drag

```
import Tkinter

class Cell():
    FILLED_COLOR_BG = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BG = "white"
    FILLED_COLOR_BORDER = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER = "black"

    def __init__(self, master, x, y, size):
        """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size= size
        self.fill= False

    def _switch(self):
        """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
        self.fill= not self.fill

    def draw(self):
        """ order to the cell to draw its representation on the canvas """
        if self.master != None :
            fill = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BG
            outline = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BORDER

            if not self.fill:
                fill = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BG
                outline = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill = fill, outline = outline)

class CellGrid(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master, rowNumber, columnNumber, cellSize, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width = cellSize * columnNumber , height = cellSize * rowNumber, *args, **kwargs)

        self.cellSize = cellSize

        self.grid = []
        for row in range(rowNumber):

            line = []
            for column in range(columnNumber):
                line.append(Cell(self, column, row, cellSize))

            self.grid.append(line)

        #memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
        self.switched = []

        #bind click action
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)  
        #bind moving while clicking
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.handleMouseMotion)
        #bind release button action - clear the memory of midified cells.
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.switched.clear())

        self.draw()



    def draw(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def _eventCoords(self, event):
        row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
        column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
        return row, column

    def handleMouseClick(self, event):
        row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
        cell = self.grid[row][column]
        cell._switch()
        cell.draw()
        #add the cell to the list of cell switched during the click
        self.switched.append(cell)

    def handleMouseMotion(self, event):
        row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
        cell = self.grid[row][column]

        if cell not in self.switched:
            cell._switch()
            cell.draw()
            self.switched.append(cell)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = Tk()

    grid = CellGrid(app, 50, 50, 10)
    grid.pack()

    app.mainloop()
```

And error:

```
NameError: name 'Canvas' is not defined
```

How can I change my code in order to runnig this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not defined all right, I wonder how could it run on Py3, unless Tkinter there dumped Canvas into your namespace somehow.

You probably wanted to do `class CellGrid(Tkinter.Canvas)`, but I don't remember the exact structure of Tkinter offhand, so it might be in a subpackage or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import elements of module you want to use, in your case:

```
from Tkinter import Canvas, Tk
```

You can also do:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

but it is not recomended way of doing. Your code may not work right, if you use many modules, and they two of them happend to have same name of method.

Last way is just

```
import Tkinker
```

but then every time you use element of this module, you need to add full path so if you wanna use `Canvas`, you need to use`Tkinker.Canvas`.

Also remember that in Python 2.7 you `import Tkinter` and in 3.X `import tkinter`